# Preventing Python from escaping characters in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, escaping

I need to create several strings using the `format()` method and store them in a list. (Ultimately, the strings will be used as regular expressions but that's not important at this stage.)

I've defined a string that presents potential spaces:

```
space_sep = r"[\s_\-–—]*"   # which defines several characters used as separators
```

The full string is produced using:

```
myStr = """category\d{spc}\d{{3}}""".format(spc = space_sep)
```

...which produces the complete string (as expected):

```
category\d[\s_\-–—]*\d{3}
```

However, if I use the same method to create several strings and store them in a list, the backslashes are automatically escaped. As these strings will be used as regexes, that is not what is wanted:

```
myLst = ["""category\d{spc}\d{{3}}""".format(spc = space_sep),
         """group\d{spc}\d{{3}}""".format(spc = space_sep)]
```

This produces a list of strings with all the backslashes escaped:

```
['category\\d[\\s_\\-–—]*\\d{3}', 'group\\d[\\s_\\-–—]*\\d{3}']
```

This is not what is needed. Instead, I want to produce unescaped strings, such as:

```
['category\d[\s_\-–—]*\d{3}', 'group\d[\s_\-–—]*\d{3}']
```

I've tried using r to identify a raw string but it doesn't work (at least, not in any of the ways I've tried). Is there a way to prevent Python from automatically escaping characters in a list of strings? (I'm running Python 3.6.1 on Windows 7 and can't upgrade either.)

Comment: "Instead, I want to produce unescaped strings, such as:" You seem to be confused. `'\d'` *is the same string as* `'\\d'`, because there is no `\d` escape sequence for strings (never mind regexes). Similarly for `'\s'` and `'\\s'`. Your list `['category\\d[\\s_\\-–—]*\\d{3}', 'group\\d[\\s_\\-–—]*\\d{3}']` contains strings that have *single* backslashes, *not* double backslashes. They show up doubled because Python puts strings in a canonical form for output.

Comment: "which produces the complete string (as expected):" Yes, that's what you get if you `print(myStr)`. If you instead view `myStr` at the interpreter prompt (equivalent to `print(repr(myStr))`, you would see the backslash escaping - just as you would see the surrounding quotation marks. When you `print` a list that contains strings, you see the `repr` of the strings - because you need to be able to tell the list `[20]` apart from the list `['20']`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for taking the time to clarify that. I had indeed got myself tied up in a bit of a knot because printing a string and printing the list of strings produced apparently different results. But if I just print a specific list item (e.g. ```print myLst[0]```) then it's clear that everything is as expected.